# Loading data from Amazon redshift to HDFS

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to load data from Amazon Redshift to HDFS.

```
val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
    > .option("forward_spark_s3_credentials", "true").option("url",
    > "jdbc:redshift://xxx1").option("user","xxx2").option("password",
    > "xxx3") .option("query", "xxx4") .option("driver",
    > "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc.Driver") .option("tempdir", "s3n://xxx5")
    > .load()
```

This is the Scala code I'm using. When I do `df.count()` and `df.printSchema()`, it's giving me the right schema and count. But, when I do `df.show()` or try to write it to hdfs it says

> S3ServiceException:The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.,Status 403,Error InvalidAccessKeyId

Answer (score 0):

you need to export below environment variables to write to s3.

**export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXX**

**export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXX**